# In DNN Content Editor HTML my style sheet not working when use any sysmbol like > this

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

In HTML For DNN 
When I am trying to Apply this

```
.overlaybox > .overlaytext {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 40px;
    max-width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
```

i write in HTML viewer but it convert into this

```
.overlaybox &gt; .overlaytext {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 40px;
    max-width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

because of this my cascading style sheet not applied for specified tag 
please help

Comment: someone edited the original post and removed the problem as stated by Masalawala.  The > character was being encoded to its html value &gt;

Comment: You can just put it on Module Settings > Header or Footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to switch the html module from rich text box to basic text box.  the basic text box does not HTML encode the input, that is what is happening here.

Comment: glad to help.  Welcome to stack overflow - if an answer solved your problem, please accept that answer.  This is best practice, helps other users with the same issues, and it also shows appreciation to the person who helped you.